# Azure Storage Javascript library "createBlobServiceWithSas" throws error: Refused to set unsafe header "user-agent"

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-blob-storage

Using the Azure Storage JS Client library to upload an image throws an error: "Refused to set unsafe header "user-agent""

All requests in the network tab are 200 or 201, it appears like the xhr requests are working. Is it possible to not set this header or filter it out before the post call? I would like to avoid this error in the console.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node#azure-storage-javascript-client-library-for-browsers

Answer (score 2):

Have tested the sample `azurestoragejs-2.9.100-preview` in link you mentioned, it causes no error on my side(both Chrome and Firefox).

Open `azure-storage.blob.js` lib file, search variable `var unsafeHeaders` and check whether `user-agent` is in its list. I saw it on my side and reproduce your problem after deleting it. So it might be missing in your file.

If your lib is unbroken, you can ignore this "error" as nothing goes wrong and it's all implemented by storage lib and browser.

Explanation:

When http request executes, method in this lib will make sure headers in `unsafeHeaders` list won't be set by `xhr`. If not, browsers will throw warnings as you have seen, because it's a requirement of [xhr standard](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-xmlhttprequest-setrequestheader).

See remarks in this lib.

> This check is not necessary, but it prevents warnings from browsers about setting unsafe headers.To be honest I'm not entirely sure hiding these warnings is a good thing, but http-browserify did it, so I will too.

Everyting does work on your side may have proved the check is `not necessary`. Also in [xhr standard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-header-name), `user-agent` is no more an unsafe header, but browser doesn't catch up.